# Eigenvector of Hadamard matrix functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, eigenvector, hadamard-product

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with SVD $X=UDV^T$. Are there known results regarding the eigenvectors of $Y=X^{\odot g}$? I am mainly interested in simple functions such as $g(z)=z^2$, i.e. $Y_{ij}=X^2_{ij}$.

I have tried finding it in [Topics in Matrix Analysis](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/topics-in-matrix-analysis/B988495A235F1C3406EA484A2C477B03#) without any luck so far.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!